# Sd and internal the same?

Tags: tablet

Ok so I have a Tesla TTL7 tablet with android version 4.4 and the thing is my current apps take like 1.37 GB and I have 5 GB of space remaining but I still cannot download apps. And as I mentioned in the title it says that my internal and sd memory are the same thing(sd adds space to internal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage on SD-card and internal storage are quite different.

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By
>   default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.
>
> Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage"
>   that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media
>   (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage. Files
>   saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified
>   by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a
>   computer.
>
> Caution: External storage can become unavailable if the user mounts
>   the external storage on a computer or removes the media, and there's
>   no security enforced upon files you save to the external storage. All
>   applications can read and write files placed on the external storage
>   and the user can remove them.

This explanaton is given on the [Android-Developer-Site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)